# CA certificate - AWS EC2 SSL

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, web-scraping

Using RStudio on a AWS EC2 instance, I am scraping a website and I receive an error saying:

> "status was 'Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA
>   certificates'"

I then added the following line before but it did not change anything:

```
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
```

I am thinking this might have to be related to the "Security Groups" on the instance EC2 but I really do not know what kind of parameters I should put it to mention that it is okay if this website does not have certificate.

Any help much appreciated !
Thanks.

Comment: What web site are you scraping? Did you try running `sudo update-ca-certificates`? Did you try debugging with command-line `curl`?

Comment: I would prefer to keep the website for me if that's alright. I just did sudo yum install ca-certificates but nothing changed.